# Lync Database - Mobile vs PC users

Tags: sql-server, lync

G'day all,
I'm looking to find out how Microsoft distinguishes between mobile and non-mobile subscribers/users in Lync's database (not SDK or API!), would anyone be able to suggest a direction to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the table 'rtcdyn' in the Pool Configuration Store.  Here is blog post that describes it in more detail.  If I find anything else I'll append it to my answer.

http://blog.insidelync.com/2011/04/the-lync-server-databases/

Comment: It's a decent resource but it doesn't contain much about the difference of mobile vs a PC version. You can, perhaps, see it from versions difference but it is inconclusive.

Comment: I wasn't in a place where I can access my Lync Server when I responded.  I'll check it out when I am back at my office.